# How can I zoom in rxgraph?

Tags: ros, rxgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran the rxgraph but the nodes and topics are too small to read them directly. How can I zoom into the graph so I can read it easily??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10344/how-can-i-zoom-in-rxgraph??/) by [unda91](https://answers.ros.org/users/727/unda91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can zoom using the scroll wheel on your mouse, or by double clicking on the node(s) you're interested in.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-08-05**:
Thx. Scroll wheel works good, double clicking doesn't work both on my machines for some reason. Ubuntu 10.10